# Python matplotlib and plotting date time information

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

I have generated the following data from an API. I am now trying to plot a graph using `matplotlib` that displays the dates and the humidity for those days. The problem is that I have different times for those days. How do I filter by time so that it shows only the time of day that I select. I have attached a python file with only the relevant data taken out from my program to be able to do this.

I am new to `matplotlib` and `numpy`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

'''This is the data generated'''

date=[datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 21, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 3, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 6, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 9, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 21, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 3, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 6, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 9, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 21, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 3, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 6, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 9, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 21, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 3, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 6, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 9, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 21, 0)]

  humidity=[69, 70, 64, 68, 76, 81, 76, 76, 67, 54,
      53, 59, 68, 81, 80, 73, 65, 59, 57, 64,
      92, 82, 81, 81, 71, 63, 60, 61, 67, 76,
      80, 75, 67, 83, 81, 82]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas that will simplify this case.
The code would be:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''This is the data generated'''

date=[datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 18, 0),
  ...,
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 21, 0)]

humidity=[69, 70, 64, 68, 76, 81, 76, 76, 67, 54,
      53, 59, 68, 81, 80, 73, 65, 59, 57, 64,
      92, 82, 81, 81, 71, 63, 60, 61, 67, 76,
      80, 75, 67, 83, 81, 82]

df = pd.DataFrame(humidity, index=date)
df.plot(figsize=(16, 6), marker='o')
plt.show()
```

That gives you the following graph:
[image]

It would be also possible to do it with pure matplotlib and more customized graph.
An example could be the following one:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''This is the data generated'''

date=[datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 18, 0),
  ...,
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 15, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 18, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 6, 21, 0)]

humidity=[69, 70, 64, 68, 76, 81, 76, 76, 67, 54,
      53, 59, 68, 81, 80, 73, 65, 59, 57, 64,
      92, 82, 81, 81, 71, 63, 60, 61, 67, 76,
      80, 75, 67, 83, 81, 82]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,9), dpi=100)
OX_ticks_str = [dateRef.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for dateRef in date]
OX_ticks_pos = range(len(humidity))
plt.plot(range(len(humidity)), humidity, color='b', alpha=1.0, marker='o', ms=3, mfc='b', mec='b', label='Humdity')
plt.title('Humidity', weight='bold')
plt.xticks(OX_ticks_pos, OX_ticks_str, rotation=40, horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=7)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, fontsize='large', framealpha=0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In this case,it gives you the following graph:
[image]

Comment: I still can't run it and I have not got panda. I just want to be able to plot times using matplotlib in the x axis. The times are in the format of datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 21, 0)'. This is the data held in the multidimentional list: [datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 21, 0)] as I have reduced the size of the data set.

Comment: How can I plot this data simply. I would like the times displayed on the x axis. I am new to matplotlib and have been searching for days to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try the second option? It uses only matplotlib, and it should work. I am using version 1.5.1, but looking to documentation it should work with most of the versions as nothing specific/strange is used. Can you run the second code that I posted (changing all date list to the full one of course) and explain better the errors?

Comment: This is the error that I am getting:                                                    
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nosh/Desktop/c.py", line 20, in <module>
    OX_ticks_str = [dateRef.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for dateRef in date]
  File "/Users/nosh/Desktop/c.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
    OX_ticks_str = [dateRef.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for dateRef in date]
AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: `ellipsis`'? What is that? No idea. Are you using python and importing `datetime` correctly? You have to use exactly `import datetime` instead of `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: yes, I just copied and pasted your code into python and ran it

Comment: If I upload my latest code, the full program, would you show me how to put the time in the x axis?

Comment: Edit your question and add your code to check how you do it, which will help to understand what's wrong in your code.